# Toggle the display of a ul submenu only if parent li is clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I've looked through some of the other questions on this site that I thought might help, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638055/how-to-make-a-submenu-display-only-if-the-li-is-clicked) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660855/hide-all-visible-ul-when-parent-li-is-clicked), but they don't seem to answer my question. What I have is the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".has-submenu ul").hide();
  $(".has-submenu").click(function() {
   $(this).children("ul").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see from this snippet, the submenu is hidden regardless of whether I click "Item 2" or "Sub Item 1". I realize this is because "Sub Item 1" is part of the `<li class="has-submenu">`, so of course once it's clicked it goes through and toggles the sub menu. The CSS is doing what it's supposed to be doing, I just don't know how to tweak the CSS to say "Only hide the submenu if the parent `li` was clicked. I tried modifying the JQuery `click` function to look for `$(".has-submenu a")` to specify that it should only do that if that specific element was clicked, but that didn't seem to help.

I'm sure it's an easy fix, I just don't know how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(".has-submenu > a")` for click to select `a` that is direct child of `.has-submenu` only and then use `next()` to target `ul`

```js
$(".has-submenu ul").hide();
$(".has-submenu > a").click(function() {
  $(this).next("ul").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must change your selector to `$(".has-submenu>a")` and toggle its `.siblings("ul")` on click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".has-submenu ul").hide();
  $(".has-submenu>a").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works even if `.has-submenu` has more than one item.

```js
$(".has-submenu ul").hide();
$(".has-submenu > a").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('ul').each(function(){$(this).toggle();});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```